# zeppelin with spark 1.5.2 standalone cluster error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, apache-spark-1.5

I have downloaded the Zeppelin 0.5.5 binary into a redhat 6.3 instance. I have also built spark 1.5.2 successfully. Now, I would like to have zeppelin use that spark version instead of the precompiled one that comes with zeppelin.

For that, I have edited conf/ so that it contains only this uncommented line:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/home/eron/spark-1.5.2/
```

I have also edited the zeppelin GUI so that now I have Master set:

```
master = spark://master:7077
```

I then hit restart and tried to go through the tutorial again:

```
val bankText = sc.textFile("/mnt/zeppelin-0.5.5-incubating-bin-all/bank.csv")
```

> org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
>   at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
>   at
>   org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
>   at
>   org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
>   at
>   org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
>   at
>   org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:220)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:205)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:211)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93)
>   at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:207)
>   at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:170) at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:304)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Also, just doing

```
sc
```

yields:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182) at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:139)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:192)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93)
>   at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:207)
>   at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:170) at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:304)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Took 0 seconds.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version of Zeppelin 0.5.5 will not work with any Apache spark version higher than 1.5.0 so you will need to download Zeppelin 0.6.0 from github and recompile using the command "mvn clean package -Pspark-1.5 -DskipTests" Zeppelin 0.5.5 builds Spark 1.4 by default.

Comment: thanks for the info. That wasn´t very clear from the zeppelin web.

Comment: Thanks a lot Panashe!!